# What is the correct way to create a loop using two values of the same position on different lines?

Tags: python

After collecting values, `list_3` is created for example:

```
list_1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list_2 = ['e','f','g','h']
list_3 = [list_1,list_2]
```

I would like to print the results in this model text sequence:

```
a and e
```

```
b and f
```

```
c and g
```

```
d and h
```

I tried to use it as follows:

```
for i, event in enumerate(list_3):
    print(list_3[i][i] + ' ' + list_3[i+1][i])
```

But it returned in error:

```
    print(list_3[i][i] + ' ' + list_3[i+1][i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What is the correct way to proceed to recover the corresponding prints?

Comment: It's much easier to find answers for this kind of thing when you know the terminology.

Comment: In fact @KarlKnechtel . Worst of all is that I searched but couldn't find the answer exactly because of the words to be searched!

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip()` to traverse multiple lists in parallel:

```
for x, y in zip(*list_3)):
    print(f"{x} and {y}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `enumerate`, use `zip`. `zip` allows you to iterate over the two lists together:

```
for i,j in zip(list_1, list_2):
    print(i + ' and ' + j)
```

Output:

```
a and e
b and f
c and g
d and h
```